# Measure Calculates very Slowly

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI data model with 2 tables.

**Customer**:

| customer_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2024-01-01 |
| 2 | 2023-04-09 | 2023-09-08 |
| 3 | 2024-01-05 | 2024-03-02 |

**Calendar**:

| date |
| --- |
| 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-02 |
| ... |
| 2023-01-03 |

I would like to calculate the number of customers active per day.  The following measure works, but since the data model has millions of rows, it is very slow.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
customer_count = 

var calendar_filtered = filter('calendar', day('calendar'[Date]) == 1) -- for speed, only use the first day of each month

var customer_count = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTA(customers[customer_id]),
        FILTER(
            customers,
            maxx(calendar_filtered, [Date]) >= customers[start_date] &&
            maxx(calendar_filtered, [Date]) <= customers[end_date]
        )
    )

return
customer_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code which is joining the 'Customers' and 'Calendar' tables

```
customer_count = 
VAR CustomerDates =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CROSSJOIN ( 'Customers', 'Calendar' ),
        "Active",
            IF (
                'Customers'[start_date] <= 'Calendar'[Date]
                    && 'Customers'[end_date] >= 'Calendar'[Date],
                1,
                BLANK ()
            )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'CustomerDates' ),
        'CustomerDates'[Active] = 1
    )
```

You may also try using filter

```
ActiveCustomerCount =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Customer'),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'),
        'Calendar'[date] >= 'Customer'[start_date] &&
        'Calendar'[date] <= 'Customer'[end_date]
    )
)
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect a CROSSJOIN to be an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: try it and pls keep me posted I will help you as much as I can.

Comment: @AlexisOlson  how about using filter ?

Comment: @AhmedAminShahin, I don't think the syntax of the crossjoin measure is correct.

Comment: @joshbrows what's the problem with it?

Comment: @AhmedAminShahin it tells me "Table CustomerDates does not exist."

Comment: it supposed to select a column called date within the customer table, this not how it goes!!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for avoiding the MAXX() which can be computationally expensive

```
CustomerCountOptimized = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('Customers'),
        'Customers'[start_date] <= CurrentDate,
        'Customers'[end_date] >= CurrentDate
    )
```

What you have done by only considering the first day of each month, may reduce the computation load but also limits the granularity of your insights to monthly rather than daily. You may need then a summarized table rather than a measure.

Comment: Using a variable here is the important part. `MAX('Calendar'[Date])` is just syntax sugar for `MAXX('Calendar', Calendar'[Date])` under the hood.

Comment: I don't see much of a speed gain when I only use the first day of the month, which I find strange.  Your measure isn't much faster either.